# Bootstrap 4 - element min-width changes to >17 million px after last breakpoint is reached on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, sass, bootstrap-4, magento2

I am using bootstrap 4 for my magento 2 theme. If I change the device width to 575, then a weird bug is triggered causing some elements on my page to become almost 20 millions pixels width.

It works perfectly fine in other browsers. I also tested in on the mobile firefox browser of my android device... same.

**Breakpoints:**

```
xxs: 0,
xs: 450px,
sm: 576px,
md: 768px,
lg: 992px,
xl: 1200px,
xxl: 1500px
```

**UPDATE**: I just added a new breakpoint at 450px. So try a width below 450px.

[image: gif]]

**UPDATE:**

It starts to get weird at the `<div>` with classes `column main`.

If I set `max-width: 100%` on this element, then it looks somewhat better.

I need to understand why it does happen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the max width for xs is not defined in `scss\_variables.scss`!

**Before:**

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1500px
) !default;

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px,
  xxl: 1440px
) !default;
```

**After:**

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1500px
) !default;

$container-max-widths: (
  xs: 540px,
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px,
  xxl: 1440px
) !default;
```

---

I actually decided to add more breakpoint, otherwise the max-width is way too high on small devices.

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  xs_sm: 341px,
  xs_md: 381px,
  xs_lg: 471px,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1500px
) !default;

$container-max-widths: (

  xs: 340px,
  xs_sm: 340px,
  xs_md: 380px,
  xs_lg: 470px,
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px,
  xxl: 1440px
) !default;
```